# customize url with javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I'm looking for a simple bookmarklet to take the current URL of my website and refresh it with a couple of changes. For example:

Take the current page: https://3eesho.com/articles/2293/-/page/1

and change it to: https: //3eesho.com/articles/2293

then store that new URL in hash table.

I tried searching for a bookmarklet that can do this but I couldn't find one. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Even a bookmarklet that does something like this that I can edit to suit my needs.

Comment: in what language you want to do it PHP or javascript  ??

Comment: added an answer i hope it will work as per your requirement. about hash table . i don't know what it is ... if you can explain more

Comment: hash table it's like dynamic array.

Comment: now are you getting url format correctly ?

Comment: yes , but i want to explain my work to you my app post to facebook wall when you read article on my site just like yahoo but the problem is the article on my site Distributed on several pages and every time the user read article and switch from page to another the app post to here wall. so I need my app post one time to wall.so what I can do

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's `split(" ")` function

```
var link="https://3eesho.com/articles/2293/-/page/1";
var splitlink=link.split("/");
```

`Example :` http://jsfiddle.net/ipsjolly/gk72d/3/